# CodeIgniter data from Controller to View

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create `form` in view file with array $data, like this:

Controller:

```
    $data = array(
    'name'        => 'username',
    'id'          => 'username',
    'class'   => 'form-control',
    'placeholder'        => 'username here',
);
$this->load->view('login_page', $data);
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_input($data); ?>
```

It doesn't work, I should use $name; $id; $class; $placeholder, but how to do it with form?

Comment: You passed data at view wrong way. use this way `$this->load->view('login_page', array('data'=>$data));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you pass array to the view it turns array keys into variables.
so for example in controller

```
$data['test'] = 'value';
```

if you pass **$data** to the view

```
$this->load->view('view_page', $data);
```

you wont be able to access **$data** array in the view, but rather - **$test** variable

so

```
echo $test;
```

would work fine

basically you need to insert your form data into another array
like so

```
$data = array(
    'form_data' => array(
        'name'          => 'username',
        'id'            => 'username',
        'class'         => 'form-control',
        'placeholder'   => 'username here',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the input config in an array so it doesn't get broken out into separate variables.

```
$data = array( 
        'formParams' => array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
              'class'       => 'form-control',
              'placeholder' => 'username here'
        )
        );

$this->load->view('login_page', $data);
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_input($formParams); ?>
```